# Getting SIM state in GsmServiceStateTracker.java

Tags: android

How can I get to know whether SIM is present or not in GsmServiceStateTracker.java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

TelephonyManager.getDefault().getSimState() returns the SIM state.

Possible values for SIM state:

SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN

SIM_STATE_ABSENT

SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED

SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED

SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED

SIM_STATE_READY